# Difference between ten minute walk and ten minutes' walk,

Tags: word-usage, attributive-nouns

What is the difference between **ten minute walk** and **ten minutes' walk**, are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same, but for different reasons.

For the apostrophe version, note that you should use **minute's** only for one minute, and **minutes'** for more than one minute. Note that the apostrophe has moved in the plural. For an explanation, check out [this link](http://www.grammar.cl/rules/genitive-case.htm).

When you add the apostrophe, you make a genitive, so it means the same as ten minutes **of** walking: the ten minutes is a measure of a quantity of walking, ie a distance.

Without the apostrophe, it's like a [compound noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm), with **ten minute** describing **walk**: that's why minute is singular. You are talking about a walk with a duration of ten minutes. Ten minutes is simply a measure of time.

According to this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minute%20walk%2Cminute%27s%20walk%2C%20minutes%27%20walk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cminute%20walk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminute%20%27s%20walk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminutes%20%27%20walk%3B%2Cc0), the genitive form used to be the only one: The non-apostrophe form came into existence around 1910, and became the most widely used in 1980.

This switch in usage is probably a result of changes in society's attitude to walking. It is no longer the normal means of getting about, but a form of exercise. You have to exercise for ten minutes, rather than to get from A to B.

Comment: Ten minute is an adjectival form. And ten minutes of walk would be wrong. However, you could say: ten minutes' walking, which means: ten minutes of walking.

Comment: @Lambie, read Giambattista's answer to the duplicate question. You will see that he correctly describes **ten minute** as an attributive noun, not an adjective. Likewise, ten minutes of X is also a noun usage, for example "ten minutes of thought would have saved you a lot of trouble". Using "walk" rather than "walking" sounds ungrammatical in this context but its usage is widespread.

Comment: @Lambie, the usage of walk rather than walking is equivalent to the usage of sleep rather than sleeping. "I barely got ten minutes' sleep last night" cf. "the sea is ten minutes' walk from my house". See definition 1.1 in the nouns section of this: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/walk.

Comment: A@JavaLatte I don't use the term attribute noun. I  prefer adjectival use of a noun. Why can't one say: ten minutes' walk? Because if you spell out the genitive, you get: ten minutes of walk. Obviously agrammatical.  Whereas: with ten minutes' walking, if you do the same thing, you get: ten minutes of walking. And that's OK. The sea is a ten minute walk from my house. The sea is ten minutes' walking from my house. I disagree the dictionary. It is not logical.

Comment: @Lambie, who told you that language was logical? Anyway, whether you like it or not, sleep and sleeping are both nouns, and walk and walking are both nouns.

Comment: The boy's shoes-the shoes of the boy; the cake's frosting; the frosting of the cake, etc. etc. It has to work: ten minutes' walk does not work.

Comment: Every language on this earth has a logic to it. And though there are anomalies or exceptions, here one can show that ten minutes' walk does not follow the logic of how "genitives" work in English. It's not about sleep and sleeping being nouns. It's about using an apostrophe s instead of /of/. That's all.

Comment: @Lambie: http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com.eg/2014/01/a-ten-minute-walk-ten-minutes-walk.html

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is practically the same but the grammar is not.
You can use this in a couple of ways:

> ten-minute walk
>   ten-minute-long walk
>   ten minutes' walk
>   ten minutes of walk
>   walk of ten minutes

Notice the **hyphens** in the first two cases. Words like those are called compound adjectives. It's like saying *"short walk"* but you specify it as *"ten-minute"* or *"ten-minute-long"*.
The other three are possessive, and even though the possessor and the possessed switch places in case four and five, they still mean the same thing: a walk that lasted for ten minutes.
It should be noted that you use the last form also when you talk about some experience, something with importance, e.g.

> a walk of the year
>   a run of the century
>   a journey of a lifetime

but in these cases the meaning does differ, the time is not the duration, it's usually a time frame in which something happened. It's like saying *"the best walk this year"*, *"the best run of this century"* and *"the best journey of your life"*.

Comment: Can you use _lenth_ instead of _long_, as in _a three-quarter **length** coat_?